# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.1:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Unable to process template -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I was trying to follow the steps here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Run with "mvn clean install -X " to know the exact issue. Seems the  template thing is particular with your project.